# Windows Host OS appears to ignore injected packets via linux sendto using raw socket

Tags: networking, raw-sockets

I am sending packets to a Windows network card (`eth1`) using the Linux `sendto()` function and a RAW socket (`socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);`). However, although the packets are addressed to the IP address of the network card, the host OS appears to "ignore" the packets.

For example, the network card has IP 192.168.1.2, and my userspace application sends a network packet containing a ping addressed to 192.168.1.2. I can observe in Wireshark the ping arrive on the network device at 192.168.1.2, however no reply is generated. The TTL on the ping is non-zero, so I'm lost as to why the host OS would appear to "ignore" packets destined for it.

Equivalently, if I create a UDP socket and bind it listening to 192.168.1.2 on port 5050, and then send a userspace UDP packet addressed to 192.168.1.2 on port 5050, the packet is never delivered to the port.

What would cause a packet to be ignored by the network card that receives it?

Is there any socket flag needed if I'm sending packets in from userspace (over a custom IP tunnel) to force processing of the packets, as if they came from a router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the native windows firewall, disabling the firewall fixed this issue.

In addition, if republishing network packets on a network device, if a single device (mac addr) is publishing multiple ip packets from various source ips, windows may filter out packets with the assumption that mac<->ip is a unique 1:1 mapping.